# Setting XML nested nodes from C# with XElement

Tags: c#, xml

I'm modifying some legacy code and need to parse/write to XML with C#. I'm trying to set the value of a nested element but am not getting any joy. It should be very simple but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the XML template:

```
<my:productReport>
    <my:productId>1</my:productId>
    <my:company>MyCompany</my:company>
    <my:productPerson>
        <my:productPersonId xsi:nil="true"></my:productPersonId>
        <my:productPersonName></my:productPersonName>
    </my:productedBy>
</my:productReport>
```

I can set the company no problem with:

```
 XElement companyEle = doc.Root.Element(myNameSpace + "company");
   companyEle.Value = value;
```

But how can I add a product person ID and Name? There may be more than one personID/personName elements to be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? You mentioned needing to set and add, sorry if I misunderstood. Also, if you didn't notice, the template you gave has the wrong closing tag for productPerson.

```
//Get collection of productPerson elements
IEnumerable<XElement> prodPersons = productReport.Elements("productPerson");
foreach(XElement pp in prodPersons)
{
  //Set values
  pp.Element("productPersonId").Value = "1";
  pp.Element("productPersonName").Value = "xxx";
}

//Add a productPerson element
XElement prodPersonEle =
     new XElement("productPerson",
          new XElement("productPersonId","3"),
          new XElement("productPersonName", "Somename")
     );


//Add prodPersonEle to whatever parent it belongs.
```